# Conditionally apply validations laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-validation

I want to validate my input against the database, What i tried is,

```
$input = Input::all();

$notificationRules = Array(
    'isReadAll' => 'required|boolean',
    'visitedNotificationId' => 'required|exists:notification',
);

$runValidation = Validator::make($input, $validations);
```

but i need to check the existence **only if**  `isReadAll == false`, Is there any option in laravel validations or do i need to create a custom one ?

Comment: Please look into this: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the [Conditionally Adding Rules](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#conditionally-adding-rules) section:

```
$runValidation->sometimes('visitedNotificationId', 'required|exists:notification', function($input)
{
    return ( ! ($input->isReadAll));
});
```